# How do I obtain row counts for protected sheets?

Tags: c#, excel-2007, excel-interop

I am using [Excel._Worksheet.UsedRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.usedrange%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)`.Rows.Count` property to get a count of populated rows.  This worked up until I added [protect worksheet](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/password-protect-worksheet-or-workbook-elements-HP010078580.aspx?CTT=1).  Now, my UsedRange returns a value equal to the length of the unlocked cells per column (100) instead of the number of populated cells per column (54).  UsedRange returned 54 before I protected the sheet.

Now I get

`NullReferenceException` when I call ToString()

```
string columnValue = worksheet.Range[currentColumnString, currentColumnString].Value2.ToString();//currentColumnString = A55, Value2=null
```

This is because `UsedRange.Rows.Count` is wrong.  How can I get row counts with a protected sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `Excel._Worksheet.Rows.Count`... these http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.alloweditranges%28v=office.14%29.aspx can help to narrow down which Cells are protected.